# Is "null-conditional operator" a misnomer?

Tags: c#, computer-science

It's my understanding that sub-expressions must always be evaluated before the parent expression.

```
(a + b) / (c + d)
```

In the above example, `a + b` and `c + d` are always evaluated before division. My understanding is that this is true *even when a, b, c, and d are all nullable*, and that this is the behavior of a true operator.

However, with the assumption that `a` is null and that these methods exist, if we write

```
(a?.Add(b))?.DivideBy(c?.Add(d))
```

none of the methods are executed, even when `b`, `c`, and `d` are not null.

Is it appropriate for `?.` to be referred to as an operator, or is that a bastardization of the term?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: It’s as appropriate as it is for `.` (which is also an operator, yes). The “may not be evaluated” part isn’t the part that makes it not like an operator, cf. `&&`, `||`, `??`, and `… ? … : …`.

Comment: @Ry- I disagree. The member access operator attempts to execute, and within the execution throws an exception if it is unable to execute. `?.` *prevents* the member access from occurring at all. It also prevents `c?.Add(d)` from evaluating, even though it would appear to be a sub expression.

Comment: Oh, I meant in the sense that it doesn’t really have a second operand – it’s more like `.Member` is the operator. But I might be wrong there and it isn’t too relevant anyway. Conditional things are normal for operators.

Comment: @all This is a question about the mathematical definition of an `operator`. How is this opinion based?

Comment: @cwharris The mathematical definition of an operator is irrelevant when discussing C# language syntax.  What matters is the C# language's definition of an operator.

Comment: @Servy honestly that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

> ?. and ?[] null-conditional Operators
>
> Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null **before performing** a
>   member access (`?.`) or index (`?[]`) operation; **returns** `null` if the
>   left-hand operand evaluates to `null`.

(**bold** is mine). In your case

```
 (a?.Add(b))?.DivideBy(c?.Add(d))
```

can be rewritten as

```
 a                        // a is null
   ?.Add(b)               // left is null? Yes; then propagate null - don't compute Add
   ?.DivideBy(c?.Add(d))  // left is null? Yes; then propagate null - don't exec DivideBy
```